# session expire at browser close is not set properly django

Tags: python, django

I set SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE to True in settings.py and am trying to get the value, but it returns True first, and then False later.

In settings.py

```
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
```

In views.py

```
def login(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':  
        print 'First call: is expired at the browser close', request.session.get_expire_at_browser_close() 

        if not request.POST.has_key('remember_me'):               
            request.session.set_expiry(settings.LOGIN_SESSION_TIMEOUT) 
            settings.SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True  # just to makie sure          
            print 'Second call: is expired at the browser close', request.session.get_expire_at_browser_close()
   return auth_views.login(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

The first call returns True, but the second call inside POST returns False. What's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either set an expiry date, or have the session expire when the browser closes. It is not possible to do both.

The second call to `get_expire_at_browser_close` returns `False`, because you have called `set_expiry` already.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is actually pretty clear:

From `django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py`

```
def get_expire_at_browser_close(self):    
    """    
    Returns ``True`` if the session is set to expire when the browser    
    closes, and ``False`` if there's an expiry date. Use    
    ``get_expiry_date()`` or ``get_expiry_age()`` to find the actual expiry    
    date/age, if there is one.    
    """    
    if self.get('_session_expiry') is None:    
        return settings.SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE    
    return self.get('_session_expiry') == 0
```

`SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE` is implemented by not setting an expiry date on the session cookie which causes the cookie to be removed when the browser application (not the browser tab!) is closed.